# Workflow of a MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a simple MVC project and was following this tutorial to fetch data from the database.
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-data-records-from-Database-Table-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

And View Code

```
@model IEnumerable<Bittu2.student1>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(student1 student1 in Model)
        {
         <tr>
            <td>@student1.StudentId</td>
            <td>@student1.Name</td>
            <td>@student1.Branch</td>
            <td>@student1.Mobile</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code

```
namespace Bittu2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StudentDemoEntities studentDemoEntities = new StudentDemoEntities();
            return View( from student1 in studentDemoEntities.student1.Take(10) select student1);
        }
```

Edit 2:

I made some changes in my `student1.cs` class ie I implemented the Enumerable interface and defined its GetEnumerator method

```
namespace Bittu2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class student1 : IEnumerable

    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Mobile { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to understand what is really happening in the above code. Just to get some clarification.

Comment: Could you share the server side code?

Comment: What do you send to the view from controller? Is sended object is enumerable collection? Please, show the code from controller action.

Comment: @Alexander done

Comment: What is `StudentDemoEntities`? Is it IEnumerable<student1>?

Comment: It is the database Context Class @Alexander

Comment: I have not seen the link :)

Comment: @Alexander It's okay...I told you now.. I just want to fetch the data :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161955/discussion-between-alexander-and-mr-j).

Comment: I solved it... But if you can explain the work flow of this program?
I mean what is going on when I am returning the code inside View()

Comment: I do not know, what you have done. You could post and accept your own answer to help another users solve same trouble.

Comment: I mean
like what is @model IEnumerable<Bittu.student1>
doing?

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is an interface of enumerable collections. See [details on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I know that! but why are we putting @model IEnumerable<Bittu.student1>?
And how is this related to the thing we are passing inside View() in controller class?

Comment: `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator()` to get [enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides methods that allow iterate collection items. If `GetEnumerator()` is not defined in object that you send to the view, then it is not possible to iterate collection items within `foreach` statement.

Comment: @Mr.J `@model IEnumerable<Bittu.student1>` is bringing the collection of items that you sent from the controller's `return View( from student1 in studentDemoEntities.student1.Take(10) select student1);` Using this collection the table in the index page is populated. For each loop is being used to iterate over this collection.